# autocomplete in android (limit results or disabled scroll)

Tags: android, autocomplete

I need limit the results in autocomplete, or disable scroll in drop-down menu. Does anyone knows how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a subclass of ArrayAdapter that limits results to your choosing.

```
public class LimitArrayAdapter<T> extends ArrayAdapter<T> {

    final int LIMIT = 5;
    //overload other constructors you're using
    public LimitArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                             List<T> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return Math.min(LIMIT, super.getCount());
    }

}
```

Ofcourse, this is how you'll use it

```
autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(new LimitArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                                                              android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,
                                                              list));
```